# Can multiple domains run the same index?

Tags: html, hosting, multiple-domains

Does anybody know if I have multiple domains (http://site1.gr,   http://site2.gr, http://site.gr, ....) is it possible to run the same `index.html`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Via using the same DocumentRoot, or using an Alias, or using a symbolic link on the filesystem, having a single configuration with multiple hostname, or a host of other approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have just to configure your virtual host with the same path.

More informations: [vhosts configurations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/examples.html)

Please see the below example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.site1.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.site2.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to create a virtual host files. I suggest you to search in google to know how to do that. That depends your OS.

Answer (score 1):

yes. you only need to set the same DNS to every domain and then configure your server (virtual hosts) to route them to the same folder. You can differentiate used domain name by comparing the value in $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] (in PHP).
Be careful about content duplicates as search robots ban them.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on the platform you are using as a web serevr (ie IIS or apache)

usually those configuration are being made at the web server level
long story short you need to set an A record to the same server on your domain management system then in the server itself you should apply the domains binding to a website

https://serverfault.com/questions/41941/what-is-the-apache-equivalent-of-iis-site-bindings

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

since the domains are all directed to the same server and, in turn, the server directs all traffic to a certain folder (index.html folder)
the same file will run